# "живет всю жизнь" - как сказать, не используя однокоренные слова?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Помогите исправить предложение:

*Поэтому и училась, и живет всю жизнь Нина Ивановна здесь, в нашем поселке.*

Comment: Анекдот такой был, что туристы посетили аул, в котором тогда жил самый старый грузин.  Один из туристов обратился к старику: "И Вы, что же, прожили здесь ***всю жизнь***?" Старик ответил: "Пока ещё нет..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поэтому и училась,  и живет до сих пор Нина Ивановна здесь, в нашем поселке.

Answer (score 0):

Поэтому и училась, и живёт всё время Нина Ивановна здесь, в нашем посёлке.